# How do I get the last updated date in an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, date

This code just displays the values inside the array `model.request_reports`

1. To get the most recent, I have to loop through and compare the current 
   `report.updated_at` with the last saved `report.update_at value`.  One thing to find
   out is what class the `update_at` field is and how to compare them against each other. The class is `ActiveSupport::TimeZone`
2. I need to keep track of the array index of the report that has the most recent `updated_at` as I loop so that I can access it after the loop.

The problem is, I don't know how to do this:

```
msg = ""

reports_arr = model.request_reports

reports_arr.each do |report|

    updated_at = report.updated_at

    if updated_at 
        msg = msg + "#{updated_at} --- "
        msg = msg + "#{updated_at.class}---"

    end

end

msg
```

Comment: If you want to simply get the most recently updated record, use ActiveRecord's finder methods: `model.request_reports.order('updated_at').last`

Comment: I'm not sure why you're so concerned about the class of that object. It's also unlikely that `updated_at` is not set, as any ActiveRecord model should have that populated by default upon creation unless you've done something very strange.

Comment: Just tested. This works but it gives me the last report, not the most recently updated record. In the array it is sorted by a field (due_at) which is when the report is due on. Is there another way..? Thanks!

Comment: @tadman I guess I thought I wrong. oops

Answer (score 0):

To add to @meagar comment. You should be using the DB to do sorts on tables.

With that said we need to know what DB you are using as the exact command differs for each.

Mongo w/ Mongoid would be `Model.order_by(:updated_at => 'desc').first`

Comment: I figured out my system sorts the reports by another field "due_at". Otherwise you and @meagar are correct!

Answer (score 0):

My loop had to go through the array and check by greatest date value because in the system Im using, it automatically sorts the reports array by the field "due_at" which is not the reports most recent updated record. Code below works for me.

```
msg = ""

reports_arr = model.request_reports
last_modified_report = model.last_modified_report

recent = nil
recent_report = nil

reports_arr.each_with_index do |report,index|
updated_at = report.updated_at
if index == 0 
recent = updated_at
recent_report = report
end

if updated_at > recent
recent = updated_at
recent_report = report
end

last_modified_report = recent_report

end



msg = msg + "#{recent}---"
msg = msg + "#{recent_report}---"
msg = msg + "#{last_modified_report}"

model.last_modified_report = last_modified_report
model.save(validate: false)


msg
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP's answer is only good if you absolutely cannot query the database for the info you want directly.  I assume you only want the index so you can find the most recent one?

Even if automatic sorting is on one column, your query for the data can have it sorted on a different column.

```
model.request_reports.order_by(:updated_at => 'desc').first
```

If you have a default scope that's messing with your query, you can ask for an unscoped list, although I doubt a default ordering would cause any trouble.

```
model.unscoped.order_by(:updated_at => 'desc').first
```

You can string together queries that are already written: that can be useful even if request_reports is a query or scope you have somewhere.

It will be way less expensive than getting everything, and looping through it - you are always better off finding a way to get just the info you need in a db query if you can.